# Postgresql text returning "null" string

Tags: java, android, sql, postgresql, null

I have a field in a postgresql database of text type. I retrieve it through my webserver and to my android app. I check

```
if (sampleText == null || sampleText.equals(""))
```

and both conditions are false. However, if i check

```
if (sampleText.equals("null"))
```

then it's true. It seems like postgresql stores a literal "null" string instead of just null. Is that supposed to happen?

EDIT: I never store anything in the field and there is no default. I'm just retrieving it. Is it possible it has something to do with putting it into a JSONobject

This is how I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE sampletable (
    sampletext TEXT
);
```

Comment: It's you who's storing the literal `"null"` in the database, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field directly in the database. If the field has a "null" string value instead of being empty, then that is the problem.

Comment: I checked. It's empty. It probably has nothing to do with postgresql. It's probably how I parse my http input stream into a jsonobject